On a website, simultaneously embedding multiples parts of a same video hosted by vimeo and using html container builder on elementor
Hope that i am using this forum howt should be.
Didn't knew about til i saw a question similar's mine's, but int opposite way lol.
I am currently working on my website that'll use as portfolio and to promote videography services.
But i very dont know that much about coding so im using elementor Pro on wordpress.
On it there is a page intend displaying multiples videos, pretty much in the same way Apple's displaying theirs shows and all on this page. https://www.apple.com/ca/fr/apple-tv-plus/
I already know how to display videos on my website, maybe not in the best way but with using some chatgpt html code and youtube tuto.
But i want to dislay a lot and lot of videos of the videos, but they all are between 5 and like 20 sec.
I would like to know if it could be better for my website that instead of embedding hundreds of videos, could it be better to edit them in the same video and then embed only the timecode referred
The videos are not in autoplay but they have a specific thumbnail, and when the mouse hover a video a Gif of it start playing and you have the full view icon.
But in reality its not a full view icon but a play icon that open a pop up with the video playing, but with no controls buttons. Only one icon that suggest the loop and one that suggest something like a video shuffle (and one to close the video pop up)
So either way you watch again and again the same few seconds looping or you get throw at a random mark point and the tings continue until you hit the cross.
First i wanted to embed video with loop and autoplay, and wasnt on the plan of doing it the way i described up (with the Apple content moving carroussel and the gif autoplay when hovering)
So as i said i did it using chat gpt and youtube tutos.
It worked pretty well, videos were in autoplay, simultaneously, with no control and no sound.
(Basically its's some random videos issued from different previous projects)
But they were some issues some times and the more i was adding videos the more it was lagging and site was getting slower.
So i thought that it maybe wouldn't be possible to continue with hundreds of videos and wanted to know if it would be better and possible to display (hundreds of) part of one same big video on different place of the site.
Like, as it is only asking to see one source and not hundreds shouldnt it be faster ?
Ps ; also do you think it could be possible to display a youtube hosted video and not a vimeo but without the youtube controls and logo and like only play the plain video.
(full size boxed to 1440px and blured background)
If not possible, is it at least possible to change the esthetic of the player ?
PPs : And is there a way or an AI that could give me a file with all the cuts so i wont have to set all the timecode manually ?
Ill continue to look for all of this by my side but would very very much appreciate if someone could help me for this one, for very various reasons i need to finish this website really soon so could really use some help.
Thank you very much !
also here is what the website look like ftm www.noirsoleil.com
the page where i want to do that is the /gallery one with all the colors containers representing the videos i'll soon add when the rest will be done.

Would like to apologize for poor grammar, English is not my language lol, if you need precisions to understand some parts better dont hesitate

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
